# Como simular clique de apenas um botão e não os dois?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Acho que a pergunta parece confusa, mas calma, vou explicar melhor. Tipo, em uma determinada página, existem 2 buttons com a mesma classe, tendo como diferença apenas seu value, e um atributo "origin". Exemplo:

```
<input type='button' class='botao' onclick='envia(this,0);' origin='Roll < 49' value='Roll < 49'/>

<input type='button' class='botao' onclick='envia(this,1);' origin='Roll > 51' value='Roll > 51'/>
```

Eu tentei simular os cliques usando jquery, mas não tive êxito, já que clicou nos dois botões ao mesmo tempo e não apenas em um. Meu código:

```
var button1 = $('.clDicePlay').attr('value','Roll > 51'),
            button2 = $('.clDicePlay').attr('value','Roll < 49');

button1.trigger('click');
```

Alguém pode me ajudar.
Muito obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pegar um elemento pelo valor no jQuery, utilize o seletor `value=[]`. Exemplo:

```html
<input type='button' class='botao' origin='Roll < 49' value='Roll < 49'/>

<input type='button' class='botao' origin='Roll > 51' value='Roll > 51'/>
```

```js
var button1 = $(':input[value="Roll < 49"]'),
    button2 = $(':input[value="Roll > 51"]');

button1.click(function(){
    envia(this, 0);
});

button2.click(function(){
    envia(this, 1);
});

button1.trigger('click');
```

Comment: Isso é o que eu estava procurando. Sou iniciante em JQuery.
Mas muito obrigado. Me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Defina um ID específico para cada um.

```
<input type='button' id='foo' class='bo..
```

Com isso, basta aplicar o trigger do click

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Daniel. Isso não era o que eu estava procurando, mas me ajudou com outra coisa. Muito obrigado.